# Is there any way to get the path of Sql Server folder using JAVA?

Tags: java, sql-server

Does anyone have an any idea about to get the path of SQL server folder using java code?

I am trying it for the last few days,anyone can?

I found a code to get the current environment by below code:

```
String str=System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
```

Comment: A machine can have more than one SQL Server installation, so which one do you want? Why do you want that? --- The general solution is that a user will tell your code where to find stuff like that, e.g. in a configuration file.

Comment: But in my case , consider there is only one sql installation and i need to get the path of sql server folder installed on c:\programfiles\sql\sql server

Comment: Then ask the user where it is. Unless you can clarify as to **why**, a better answer is unlikely.

Comment: what do you mean by "get it" open a file using the path you already know? or is it going to be stored somewhere in a system variable

Comment: But in some cases the sql server version will be different. So i want to get the folder name programmatically.

Comment: but how will you determine it, I mean, sql isn't connected to java in any way. java programs will connect to a database using explicit configuration you provide. if you're asking us how to determine it, there isn't a way automatically. you'll have to create a hard-coded lookup table.

Comment: Oh oh..What is lookup table?

Comment: Hey i have one doubt... cant java find the path of a folder name which start with some names?

Comment: Does your Java program even run on the computer where SQL Server is installed? If you have a JDBC connection to SQL Server you can use `DatabaseMetaData` to get the SQL Server version. Or use `select @version`. Both are much better alternatives than trying to find an installation (which you might not even be able to do, if the Java program runs somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the Windows registry using for example `com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper`

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >> SOFTWARE >> Microsoft >> Microsoft SQL Server >> Instance Names. Each instance installed on the server possesses a key inside a folder under this registry entry. Based on this key you can retrieve the directories from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >> SOFTWARE >> Microsoft >> Microsoft SQL Server >> [INSTANCE NAME] >> Setup

Comment: i am looking for java code to get the path of sql server folder